# Captcha in WebView flutter not working in Dialog

Tags: android, flutter, webview-flutter, flutter-captcha

I have a recaptcha on a html webpage, but it is not work when the `WebView` is inside Dialog (the captcha is not showing at all). It work well when the WebView is outside Dialog

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './web_view_stack.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: WebViewApp()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {

  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://nhathuocphuongthao.com/captcha'),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 100),
        // Expanded(
        //   child: Container(
        //     // color: Colors.amber,
        //     // width: 100,
        //     child: WebViewStack(controller: controller), // captcha working when WebView is outside Dialog
        //   ),
        // ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog.fullscreen(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('This is a fullscreen dialog.'),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      // width: 100,
                      child: WebViewStack(controller: controller),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Close'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text('Show Fullscreen Dialog'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**web_view_stack.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewStack extends StatefulWidget {
const WebViewStack({required this.controller, super.key});

  final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  State<WebViewStack> createState() => _WebViewStackState();
}

class _WebViewStackState extends State<WebViewStack> {
  var loadingPercentage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        WebViewWidget(
          controller: widget.controller
          ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How to make the WebView captcha work inside Dialog? I haven't found any log which relevant to the issue, anyway to debug why it's not working?